# Remove leading zeros or foreign characters in sequence number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer, string-formatting

Eg: In the below column "Sample", I need to remove columns 2, 3 & 5 because they either have a leading zero in the beginning or a special character at the start.

| Index | Sample |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 |
| 2 | 00152 |
| 3 | 09 |
| 4 | 325 |
| 5 | .1246 |

I tried changing the "Sample" column datatype to string and extracting the first character like this:

`t = df['Sample'].astype(str).str[0].astype(int)`

But it gives me this output:

`print(t)`

```
 
|   1   |  1  | 
|   2   |  1  | 
|   3   |  9  | 
|   4   |  3  |
|   5   |  0  |
```

It want it like this so that I can remove the respective rows using the index value:

```
 
|   1   |  1  | 
|   2   |  0  | 
|   3   |  0  | 
|   4   |  3  |
|   5   |  .  |
```

Is my approach correct? Can anyone please help me regarding this?
Thank a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try using `str.match` as follows:

```py
df = df[df["sample"].str.match(r'[1-9]')]
```

This would only retain rows having sample values starting with a digit, other than zero.

Comment: This would also exclude just '0'. I don't know if that's an issue for the use-case or not.

Comment: @HenryEcker In that case, we can use: `df["sample"].str.match(r'[1-9]|0(?!.)')`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the answer. I get this error though - "Can only use .str accessor with string values!". I had converted the column to string earlier.

Comment: Is `sample` _not_ a string column?  If not, then how can you "see" values like `00152` there?  Python will never print leading zeroes in front of an integer unless you explicitly use a formatting function.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You were right! Thanks buddy.